# Data is not updated in react when used useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to ReactJs .I'm trying to use the useState hook in react function base component but the value of the state is not getting updated when I am calling the function. When receiving data via websocket, it is not possible to update the data on the line graph using the construct useState and useEffect.

client receives data via websocket:

```
const myWs = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');
// обработчик проинформирует в консоль когда соединение установится
myWs.onopen = function () {
    console.log('подключился');
};

// обработчик сообщений от сервера
myWs.onmessage = function (message) {
    const jsonParse = JSON.parse(message.data);      
    try {   
      
      let temp = {x:setInterval((counter) =>{
        if(mockLineData[0].data.length >= 50){
          mockLineData[0].data.shift();
          counter++
        }
        else{
          counter++
        }
      }, 3000), y:jsonParse[0]['value_state']};
      mockLineData[0].data.push(temp);
      console.log(mockLineData[0].data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
};




export const mockLineData = [
  {
    id: "ИБП Uвх",
    color: tokens("dark").redAccent[200],
    data: [
      {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      
    ],
  },
];
```

Next I'm trying to update data in a table using the construct useState and useEffect

```
import { mockLineData as data } from "../data/dataLineGraph";

const LineChart = ({ isCustomLineColors = false, isDashboard = false }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(()=>{
      setState(data);
    },1000)
  }, []);


  return (
    <ResponsiveLine
      data={state}
      theme={{
        axis: {
          domain: {
            line: {
              stroke: colors.grey[100],
            },
          },
          legend: {
            text: {
              fill: colors.grey[100],
            },
          },
          ticks: {
            line: {
              stroke: colors.grey[100],
              strokeWidth: 1,
            },
            text: {
              fill: colors.grey[100],
            },
          },
        },
        legends: {
          text: {
            fill: colors.grey[100],
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          container: {
            color: colors.primary[500],
          },
        },
      }}
      colors={isDashboard ? { datum: "color" } : { scheme: "nivo" }} // added
      margin={{ top: 50, right: 110, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
      enableGridX={false}
      enableGridY={false}
      pointSize={8}
      pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
      pointBorderWidth={2}
      pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
      pointLabelYOffset={-12}
      useMesh={true}
      legends={[
        {
          anchor: "bottom-right",
          direction: "column",
          justify: false,
          translateX: 100,
          translateY: 0,
          itemsSpacing: 0,
          itemDirection: "left-to-right",
          itemWidth: 80,
          itemHeight: 20,
          itemOpacity: 0.75,
          symbolSize: 12,
          symbolShape: "circle",
          symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
          effects: [
            {
              on: "hover", //hover
              style: {
                itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
                itemOpacity: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default LineChart;
```

but the data is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` closes over `data` once (empty dependency array) - hence data will always be the same object, and nothing ever gets changed even if you repeatedly call `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

once you didn't send `data` to `LineChart`.
if you get it from Parent Component - add it to `props`:

```
const LineChart = ({ isCustomLineColors = false, isDashboard = false, data }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const [state, setState] = useState();
    
    .....

}
```

second - if your data changed due to lifecycle, your `useEffect` need to include `data` in `dependencies array`.

so on every change in `data` will notify by `useEffect`.

change your `useEffect` to:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setState(data);
}, [data]);
```

finally your code will be seemed:

```
const LineChart = ({ isCustomLineColors = false, isDashboard = false, data }) => {
   const theme = useTheme();
   const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
   const [state, setState] = useState();

   useEffect(() => {
     setState(data);
   }, [data]);
    
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does my code not work?

At first you set the variable `data` just in your `useEffect` hook, but where did your component get this variable? You don't initialize this variable in your LineChart component or declare this dependency as a LineChart prop so that the component get the `data` from it's parent.

Lets start with the question should your `LineChart` component be a `Smart` or `Dumb` react component (here is a good article if your not familier with this terms https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43)

I would say your `LineChart` component is a `Dumb` component, which just displays your `data` and has no business logic to get the `data` directly from the websocket.
Because of this we will introduce your `data` as a `LineChart` prop without using any `useState` or `useEffect` hooks. Maybe you are thinking now, how should the component update when we don't use a `state` combined with `useEffect`. Thats quite simple - Your component rerenders automatically when a prop changes as well.

So lets solve your problem by modifying `LineChart`:

```
const LineChart = ({ data, isCustomLineColors = false, isDashboard = false }) => {
   const theme = useTheme();
   const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
   // removed useState and useEffect hook
   return (.....)
}
```

With this component you just have to pass your new `data` as prop to your `LineChart` and your component will be updated.

My recommendation: Don't mix props with the component state as long your component just uses the prop for reading/display information.